# Check edges in a graph

Tags: python, edges

So given a graph that has a cycle from vertex S to E as it goes through every vertex then ends on E. My goal here is to remove all extra edges so that there is just a path from S to E. To help me with this I have a function called check(node) I'm not given the code for it but it returns True or False if there still exist a path from S to E such that all nodes were visited only once until we end at E.

Example:

[image]

The plan is to remove a edge from vertex a to b and then run check(node) on the mutated graph and see if it still returns True so we know its safe to remove that edge, and if it returns False then add it back. Do that for every edge so only the needed edge remains, however I have no idea how to iterate through the edges.

I stored the graphs in a dictionary

Comment: include code you've used to attempt this problem in your post

Comment: What do you want to achieve at the end of this? A cycle? Does it matter if it's any cycle, or do you want all possible cycles? Have you looked at the [networkx](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/) library? It contains (among many other things) a number of [cycle finding](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/cycles.html) algorithms that will do what you're aiming to do. Sometimes it's nice to code these things from scratch, but if you're interested, I'd take a look at that library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the approach to an Algorithms problem like this is you first figure out what algorithmic tools you can use. Most basic problems can be solved with an existing algorithm. Your first objective is to see if you can modify the problem set (ie the given graph) in such a way that you don't need to modify the algorithm, because modifying the algorithm lends to difficulties in assessing Big-O for the problem. If the graph can't be modified in any way that makes running a black boxed Algorithm easy, then you modify the algorithm. The last resort is to come up wit your own algorithm to solve the problem.

If my Algorithms recollection is correct, in short this is the Travelling Salesman Problem. If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want the shortest path possible that visits every node. You don't even need to modify your given graph in order to use the algorithm. It should theoretically find you the desired path. Only after the algorithm has run do you need to reduce the graph to its desired state. So I suggest finding some way to implement TSP to your specifications, and remove all edges that aren't part of the solution.

[Here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/traveling-salesman-problem-tsp-implementation/) is some sample code from GeeksForGeeks that could help you get started

Comment: Your approach will simply complicate things in here as @mammy don't want any sortest path, there is no point of TSP in this problem. What made you believe that he needs shortest path there is not given anything about weight associated with the edges in the first place

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal op needs a path that hits every node. 
> "exist a path from S to E such that all nodes were visited only once until we end at E."

if the edges don't have any weight, the problem resolves each edge weight to be 1. Furthermore, its not the edge traversal that matters, but node traversal. Hence why this isn't an Eulerian Tour.

Comment: if anything, this is a Hamiltonian Path. Regardless, HP can be reduced to TSP, so the algorithm is functionally the same.